# (SOLVE) Django Bootstap Modals cant render modal content

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

im trying to create a simple popup with Django Bootstrap Modal. but I can't get linked content at modals body, and when im trying to access a content its there. im so confused why my linked content cant render at modals body

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <a href="{% url 'form_view' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Open Form Modal
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Form Modal</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Your form goes here -->
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
```

form_view.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'form_submit' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Name:</label>
    {{ form.name }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">Email:</label>
    {{ form.email }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
from .forms import MyForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect



def example_view(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')


def form_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process the form data
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            # Redirect to a success page
            return redirect('success_view')
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'form_template.html', {'form': form})


def form_view(request):
    form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'form_template.html', {'form': form})
```

i want to inject form_view.html into modals at base.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django built-in template tag "include" ([link to documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include))

In your "base.html" code:

```
        ...
        <div class="modal-body">
            {% include 'form_template.html' %}
        </div>
        ...
```

You should manage your form in your view "example_view".

```
def example_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process the form data
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            # Redirect to a success page
            return redirect('success_view')
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

You'll have to manage forms error in your modal yourself or you can use a plugin like [django-bootstrap-modal-forms](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

@Philippe Thanks for helping me, but I've already solved my problem by adding ajax to my templates for injecting the view in my modals.

I'm adding this jquery and ajax to my templates:

```
<script>
$('#modal_btn').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: '{% url 'inventory:modalcontent' %}',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
      {% comment %} console.log(response) {% endcomment %}
        $('#modal-content-placeholder').append(response);
      }
    });
})
</script>
```